# JSON.Net to display Name and Value pairs for Enums

Tags: c#, json, serialization, enums, json.net

A bit of a newbie here using JSON.Net in C# -

```
string JSONOutput = (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product));
```

When I am serializing a `Product` object in my solution, I'm getting JSON out that looks like this :

```json
{
   "product":{
      "displayStatus":1,
      "drugClass":1,
      "drugType":1
   }
}
```

The `displayStatus`, `drugClass` and `drugType` values are all from `Enum`s, so the output I'm really wanting is this :

```json
{
   "product":{
      "displayStatus":{
         "name":"Visible",
         "value":1
      },
      "drugClass":{
         "name":"Generic",
         "value":1
      },
      "drugType":{
         "name":"Drug",
         "value":1
      }
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I've been looking at the `StringEnumConverter`, but the only thing I can see there is that it just returns the string of the `Enum` instead of the integer value - whereas I would like both.

Comment: You need to write a custom Json Converter. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Why do you want both? name and value?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm), like this:

```
public class EnumConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : System.Enum
{
    public override T? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var nameAndValue = new { Name = value.ToString("g"), Value = value.ToString("d") };
        var semiJson = JObject.FromObject(nameAndValue);
        semiJson.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

- I've constrained the `T` to `System.Enum`
- In the `WriteJson` I've created an anonymous type and used the [Enum Format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings) to retrieve the desired values
- I had to create a `JObject` from the anonymous type because the `JsonWriter` does not support that directly

Then you can decorate your model class with the following attributes:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter<DisplayStatus>))]
    public DisplayStatus DisplayStatus { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter<DrugClass>))]
    public DrugClass DrugClass { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter<DrugType>))]
    public DrugType DrugType { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the serialization logic looks like this:

```
var product = new Product() 
{
    DisplayStatus = DisplayStatus.Visible,
    DrugClass = DrugClass.Generic,
    DrugType = DrugType.Drug,
};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new { Product = product },
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

The `result` will look like this:

```json
{
   "product":{
      "displayStatus":{
         "Name":"Visible",
         "Value":"1"
      },
      "drugClass":{
         "Name":"Generic",
         "Value":"1"
      },
      "drugType":{
         "Name":"Drug",
         "Value":"1"
      }
   }
}
```

In order to fix the casing for `Name` and `Value` all you need to do is to pass the `serializer` to the `FromObject`:

```
var details = JObject.FromObject(nameAndValue, serializer);
```

After this the end result will look like as expected:

```json
{
   "product":{
      "displayStatus":{
         "name":"Visible",
         "value":"1"
      },
      "drugClass":{
         "name":"Generic",
         "value":"1"
      },
      "drugType":{
         "name":"Drug",
         "value":"1"
      }
   }
}
```

---

**UDPATE #1**: Add Converters to the settings

As it was indicated in the comment the `Product` class could not be amended with `JsonConverterAttribute`s. So, if you have this restriction then you can overcome on this by passing the converters via the `JsonSettings` object like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] {
        new EnumConverter<DisplayStatus>(),
        new EnumConverter<DrugClass>(),
        new EnumConverter<DrugType>()
    }
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Product = product }, settings);
```

With this approach your model will be serialization attribute free :)

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation above. However, I am unable to decorate the properties with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(EnumConverter<DrugType>))]` attributes, as they are part of another assembly. Is there a way round it without using the attributes?

Comment: @DIamondGeezer We can overcome on this limitation quite easily. The `JsonSerializerSettings` does have a `Converters` property where we can define the custom converters. GIve a minute and I'll update the post.

Comment: @DIamondGeezer I've just extended it, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Note, you shouldn't really need anything like this, there are several out of the box way to convert *enums*. For instance [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm). Eg

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

However, for sheer morbid curiosity and academic interest

**Given a converter**

```
public class SomeConverter : JsonConverter 
{

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      writer.WriteStartObject();
      writer.WritePropertyName("name");
      writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
      writer.WritePropertyName("value");
      writer.WriteValue(Convert.ChangeType(value,typeof(int)));
      writer.WriteEndObject();
   }

   public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      // ill leave this up to your imagination
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
     return objectType == typeof(Enum);
   }
}
```

**Enums**

```
public enum Bob
{
   one,
   two
}
public enum Blerge
{
   Asd,
   BFG
}
```

**And Class**

```
public class Product
{
   [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeConverter))]
   public Bob Bob { get; set; }

   [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeConverter))]
   public Blerge Blerge { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var asd = new Product()
{
   Bob = Bob.two,
   Blerge = Blerge.Asd
};

var bla = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(asd, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(bla);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Bob": {
    "name": "two",
    "value": 1
  },
  "Blerge": {
    "name": "Asd",
    "value": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: According to my knowledge the `StringEnumConverter` will not serialize both the name and the value. How do you setup that to emit both?

Comment: @PeterCsala correct! no it doesn't, but the point is, you never really need to serialize/deserialize like that anyway

Comment: I've got your point and agree, but this is the OP's requirement.